# Spinner using xml array vs Custom Adapter layout difference

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two spinners, they both works ok.

The first one loads the values from a xml array

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/my_spinner_values" />
```

[image]

And the second one

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter( this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
            optionsList );
mySpinner2.setAdapter( adapter );
```

[image]

I tried `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` and the problem happens too.

**The question**

What is the default `android.R.layout` used by android when making spinner?

Or, can I make my customadapter looks like default (without making a custom xml layout)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure I can. I can't find where to accept it. I see the changes you made but there are no options to accept them. Maybe I don't have enough reputation yet?

Comment: Spinner needs two 'getViews', one to exhibit the selected (when spinner is closed) and other to the dropdown list which is called getDropDownView. Android uses two layouts, the `simple_spinner_item` for `getView` and the `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` for `getDropDownView`.